# Android ROOM "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '`activity_id`' does not exist"

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

Getting error on API level 23 & 24, Same Query is working fine on API level 29 & 30 and getting results.

Here are the entities(Removed the variables which are not used in Query for posting here)

```
@Entity
data class Activity(@PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "activity_id") val activityId: Int)

@Entity(tableName = "JobActivities", primaryKeys = ["activity_id", "job_id"])
data class JobActivity(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "job_id")
    val jobId: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "activity_id")
    val activityId: Int,
)

@Entity(tableName = "LocationActivities")
data class LocationActivity(

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "loc_act_id")
    val locActId: String,

    val active: Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "activity_id")
    val activityId: Int?,
)
```

Query that i'm using

```
@Query("SELECT 'job' AS entity, l.activity_id , a.activity_name FROM LocationActivities l " +
"JOIN Activity a ON a.activity_id = l.activity_id WHERE loc_id = :locationId " +
"UNION SELECT 'loc' AS entity , j.activity_id , a.activity_name FROM JobActivities j " +
"JOIN Activity a ON a.activity_id = j.activity_id WHERE j.job_id = :jobId")
fun getActivities(locationId: String, jobId: Int): Flow<MutableList<ClassName>>
```

Comment: May be problems with parser on older android versions. Try to use braces around UNION's select or use @RawQuery instead of @Query without  `?` args (just string concatenation)